# write javascript array to file

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

i have loaded a file into an array using ajax and after splitting it i need to save it to the file again.This all happens onClick of a button.

```
function updatetags(){

 var alreadyexistingtags;
 var responsetext;

 var r2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
 r2.open('GET', 'tagsupdated.txt', true);
 r2.send(null);

 r2.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (r2.readyState == 4 && r2.status==200) {

        responsetext=r2.responseText;

        alreadyexistingtags=responsetext.split(' ');
        }       
  }
 }
```

i understand that javascripts are not server side and that's why i cannot do what i want,but i'm sure there must be a way to write alreadyexistingtags[ ] to tagsupdated.txt.Any help?Perhaps i should somehow pass the array to PHP?And if so how is that possible given that PHP gets executed when the page loads,when i need to wait for the button to be pressed?

Comment: Your answer is right there in your question tags...AJAX. Pass whatever you want to a PHP script and have the PHP script write out to tagsupdated.txt.

Comment: To expand it would be best to ping php first and then get php to write it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to have to use AJAX or some other method to send the data back to your server, which can then write the file out.

To do this, just create a *new* script on your server, say writearray.php, which accepts the Javascript array as input.  Then use AJAX to send a request to that file with your array.

The PHP file would look something like so (this is a highly simplified example):

```
<?php
file_put_contents("where_you_want_the_file.txt", $_POST['array']);
?>
```

It looks like you're just storing your Javascript array as a space separated list, so the Javascript would look something like this:

```
var str = your_array.join('%20');   // URL encoded spaces separating array entries
var params = "array=" + str;
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open("POST", "your_script.php", true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        // Do something on success?
    }
}
http.send(params);
```

The way this works, is you're sending a POST with a field named array, which holds the textual representation of your Javascript array.  The PHP code checks $_POST['array'] to get this value, then writes it to your file.

Note that if you want to do anything more complicated, you should look into using JSON.  And also as always be very careful with what you do with user data.

Comment: Addendum: Please remember to be *very* aware of security when implementing such functionality as it might be exploited to plant malicious content on your website.

Comment: from what i undesrtand i should do something like Stas Telnov described above: 
`r3.open('POST', 'myPHP.php', true);
...
r3.send(data_string);`
is this what you mean?and if so,in the php file where will the array be stored?I mean where i would write `$variable= "MYString";
fwrite($fh, $variable);` what should i write to pass my array to $variable?

Comment: @yiannis I added a lot more to my answer, including some sample code.  Hopefully that will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

For send data you must doing another ajax query but in .send method you have to pass a string with data
Example:

```
 var r3 = new XMLHttpRequest();
 r3.open('POST', 'writeTextWithoutTags.php', true);
 var data_string='text='+alreadyexistingtags+'&etcParams='+etc_you_params;
 r3.onreadystatechange = function()
 {
   if (r3.readyState == 4 && r3.status==200)
   {
     alert(r3.responseText);//write result
   }       
 }
 r3.send(data_string);
```

Before sent alreadyexistingtags variable you must implode array to string with separator or better to JSON string.
But in writeTextWithoutTags.php ypu must check data because javascript execute ib user brouser and you can not be sure that the data is sent from yavastsript not undergone processing intruder!

P.S. If you can access to PHP I dont understang I do not understand why you are here JS - all this actions you can douing in PHP and not to drive data from the server to the browser and back